# Visual Studio 2015 With Update 2 Installation Error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

I am going to install Universal Windows Platform (UWP) by installing visual studio 2015 with Update 2. When I end up installation I see many errors.

I have downloaded visual studio 2015 with update 2 twice and install on windows 10 enterprise/pro separately  but errors are same and I failed to install UWP toolkit.

During installation I customize the installations and also ensure the UWP toolkit checkbox selection. But when installation completes I didn't see UWP toolkit anywhere.

Its strange that how a big company Microsoft can do a general mistake giving updates two time and still we end up with many errors without UWP toolkit Installation.

Please anyone guide how to install UWP toolkit in visual studio 2015 without errors. Installation steps will also be welcome. Error screenshot is below.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Visual studio Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio updates and installations often fail if your internet connection is unstable or if you disconnect your machine during installation.

Given that all the error messages state that the "HTTP redirect request failed", please make sure your internet connection is alright.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, My internet connection is fine and fast. Visual studio 2015 with Update 2 fails now third time. As I have installed again. Please suggest any concrete solution, thanks.

Comment: Is there any offline installation setup? Can I download separately, thanks